# How to find and replace href URL with # Hashtag under Table dive ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I'm trying to replace href URL with the # hashtag

```
<td data-label="Name">
  <a href="https://mysite . com/" style="display: block;"> cabinet 1 </a>
  <div class="wbs-select">
    <select id="variations" class="wbs-variation-select" name="attribute_variations" data-attribute_name="attribute_variations" data-show_option_none="yes">
      <option value="">Select Variations</option>
      <option value="RTA">RTA</option>
      <option value="Assembled">Assembled</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span id="11-stock-status">In stock</span>
</td>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a[href^="http://"]').each(function () {
    var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
    var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("http://", "#"); // Create new url
    $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
  });
});
```

However current script only replace http:// with #, but what I looking

1. **replace entire URL with # tag**
2. **and under the table not entire page or by underclass or ID**

Comment: You mean to replace the entire href value to #? and you only want to replace those urls which are under some specific container div?

Comment: YES , it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Point 1:-** Just set the href value to "#"
2. **Point 2:-** Wrap your anchor inside a container div and in your jQuery append the container div id like below, so that it will only find anchor list which are under that container div.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#main a[href^="http://"]').each(function(){ 
          $(this).attr("href", "#"); // Set herf value
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="main">
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://asd.com">google</a>
</div>
<a href="http://ggg.com">google</a>
```

Comment: Thank you its working !! and how can tern that code only limit under div ID or Class ?

Comment: Appended div ID into jQuery selector. You can use class as well.
 $('#main a[href^="http://"]')

Comment: it will work with class as well if you want, just replace the ID with class selector.

Comment: how to stop  jump to top links on page ?

Comment: What you mean by stopping the jump?

Comment: Replace # in href with "javascript:void(0);". That will stop the page scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $('a').length; i++) {
    if ($('a')[i].href.indexOf("http://") == 0 || $('a')[i].href.indexOf("https://") == 0) {
      $(this).attr("href", "#");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td data-label="Name">
  <a href="https://example.com/" style="display: block;"> cabinet 1 </a>
  <div class="wbs-select">
    <select id="variations" class="wbs-variation-select" name="attribute_variations" data-attribute_name="attribute_variations" data-show_option_none="yes">
      <option value="">Select Variations</option>
      <option value="RTA">RTA</option>
      <option value="Assembled">Assembled</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span id="11-stock-status">In stock</span>
</td>
```